# Concatenating together .dat files containing ints and strings

Tags: python, concatenation

I have access to some data that looks something like this:

```
"""" Results are from 23 of March etc. etc 
     more lines of rubbish 
     600     5245    234   21.2   244.0  505.00 Infinity  -- 245 245.0
     610     5555    134   24.0   244.0  505.00 Infinity  -- 245 245.0 
     620     5235    534   23.0   244.0  505.00 Infinity  -- 245 245.0 
"""""
```

Essentially rows and columns. My goal is to cut the first few lines and stitch a dozen of these together. I have to be able to access components of this file later and most of the techniques I have tried bare put out anything less than a long list

```
lump_file = []

for file in os.listdir("../sif/specfit_output/2010_2011"):
    with open("../sif/specfit_output/2010_2011/"+file, 'r') as fi:
        lines = iter(fi.readline()[11:], '')
        lump_file.append(lines.next())
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Are you getting an error with this code? Can you post it or explain why the generated output is not what you want?

Comment: ha nice I didn't really ask anything, basically I want to figure out why I cant just use the 'lines' variable and vstack each line for each file in the .../2010_2011 directory, what the code above gives me is a list with each variable being each line of the file

Comment: @DanielPenchev No, the code gives you a TypeError because the first argument to `iter()` must be a callable, not a string.